# Docker file: I want to invoke one script from docker file

Tags: docker, devops

I am creating one docker image name with soaphonda.
 the code of docker file is below

```
    FROM centos:7
     FROM python:2.7
     FROM java:openjdk-7-jdk
 MAINTAINER Daniel Davison <sircapsalot@gmail.com>

#  Version
ENV   SOAPUI_VERSION  5.3.0

COPY entry_point.sh /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
COPY server.py /opt/bin/server.py
COPY server_index.html /opt/bin/server_index.html
COPY SoapUI-5.3.0.tar.gz /opt/SoapUI-5.3.0.tar.gz

   COPY exit.sh /opt/bin/exit.sh

   RUN chmod +x /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
  RUN chmod +x /opt/bin/server.py

 # Download and unarchive SoapUI
 RUN mkdir -p /opt 
 WORKDIR /opt
  RUN tar -xvf SoapUI-5.3.0.tar.gz .

  # Set working directory
  WORKDIR /opt/bin

   # Set environment
      ENV PATH ${PATH}:/opt/SoapUI-5.3.0/bin


     EXPOSE 3000

      RUN chmod +x /opt/SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/mockservicerunner.sh
     CMD ["/opt/bin/entry_point.sh","exit","pwd", "sh", "/Users/ankitsrivastava/Documents/SametimeFileTransfers/Honda/files/hondascript.sh"]
```

My image creation is getiing successfull. I want that once the image creation is done it should retag and push in the docker hub. For that i have created the script which is below;

```
   docker tag soaphonda ankiksri/soaphonda
    docker push ankiksri/soaphonda
    docker login
 docker run -d -p 8089:8089 --name demo ankiksri/soaphonda
  containerid=`docker ps -aqf "name=demo"`
   echo $containerid
    docker exec -it $containerid bash -c 'cd ../SoapUI-5.3.0;sh /opt/SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/mockservicerunner.sh "/opt/SoapUI-5.3.0/Honda-soapui-project.xml"'
```

Please help me how i can call the second script from docker file and the exit command is not working in docker file.

Comment: you have 3 `FROM` directives at the beginning of your Dockerfile, only the last one is used, as youy do not use the multi-stage build https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: you can replace containerid by `$(docker ps -lq)` and you should post the error message

Comment: It is not showing any error message. Docker creation is getting successful. I want after the creation of docker it should retag. for that, I want to come out from docker because the working directory is /opt/bin see the log
Step 20/21 : CMD ["/opt/bin/entry_point.sh"]
 ---> Running in 75e22b61c8fc
Removing intermediate container 75e22b61c8fc
 ---> fd92e712195a
Step 21/21 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 1d8e0f46b539
/opt/bin
Removing intermediate container 1d8e0f46b539
 ---> 5444b143d197
Successfully built 5444b143d197
Successfully tagged soaphonda:latest
Step 21 is /opt/bin.

Comment: What should I mention in docker file so that it can move out from the working directory which is currently coming as /opt/bin. i want to invoke another script which is stored in my local system, not in the docker container.

Comment: either the Dockerfile directive `WORKDIR` or in one `RUN` something like `cd /opt/bin &&\ ...` but definitely not `RUN cd /opt/bin` followed by `RUN mycommand` which will fail, because you are no longer in /opt/bin

Comment: if your script is in the directory of the Dockerfile, it is available, just call it

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand here is what you are specifying within the Dockerfile are the commands that gets executed when you build and run a ***Docker container*** from the image you have created using your Dockerfile.

So Docker image tag, push running should all done after you have built the Docker image from the Dockerfile. It cannot be done within the Dockerfile itself.

To achieve this kind of a thing you would have to use a build tool like Maven (an example) and automate the process of tagging, pushing the image. Also by looking at your image, I don't see any nessactiy to keep on tagging and pushing the image unless you are continuously updating the image. Also there is no point of using three FROM commands as it will unnecessarily make your Docker image size huge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to create my docker image. Is that possible from my docker file I can invoke a script which is stored locally in my system, not in the container?  please see the code below
EXPOSE 3000
RUN chmod +x /opt/SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/mockservicerunner.sh
CMD ["/opt/bin/entry_point.sh"]  till here I am able to create my docker image. Now after this I want to invoke a script which is stored locally in my system. I am able to change the directory also but the script which I am trying to run its throwing chmod permision denied. I have tried chmod +x /path but didn't work.

Comment: Is that possible I can invoke any script which is stored in my local system from the docker file?

Comment: If you want to do that, you will have to specify it on that your Dockerfile and you can do that by COPY localScript.sh /path/in/container/localScript.sh and then add RUN +X /path/in/container/localScript.sh

Comment: No the problem is The script which I am trying to invoke it should run outside the docker not inside the docker. My docker image is getting created successful and I am able to change the directory also inside the docker file. but when I am invoking the script which is stored in my local I am running this comand to invoke 
         RUN chmod +x /Users/ankitsrivastava/Documents/SametimeFileTransfers/Honda/files/hondascript.sh
error which I am getting is 
      chmod: cannot access ‘/Users/ankitsrivastava/Documents/SametimeFileTransfers/Honda/files/hondascript.sh’: No such file or directory

Comment: I have explained why you can't specify commands which that need to run outside your container cannot reside within your Dockerfile in my answer. Please refer it,